# not able to understand NAWK use

Tags: unix, nawk

I found a command which takes the input data from a binary file and writes into a output file.

```
nawk 'c-->0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c>1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=1 a=19 s="<Comment>Ericsson_OCS_V1_0.0.0.7" /var/opt/fds/config/ServiceConfig/ServiceConfig.cfg > /opt/temp/"$circle"_"$sdpid"_RG.cfg
```

It's working but I am not able to find out how...Could anyone please help me out how above command is working and what is it doing?...this nawk is too tough to understand...:(
Thanks in advance......

Comment: please help...don't give it just a thumbs down...If you need more details I will provide...I am sorry but I have no idea how nawk works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nawk is not tough to understand and is same like other languages, I guess you are not able to understand it because it not properly formatted, if you format it you will know how it's working.

To answer your question this command is searching lines containing an input text in given input file, and prints few lines before matched line(s) and few lines after the matched line. How many lines to be printed are controlled by variable **"b"** (no of lines before) and **"a"** (no of lines after) and string/text to be searched is passed using variable **"s"**.

This command will be helpful in debugging/troubleshooting where one want to extract lines from large size log files (difficult to open in vi or other editor on UNIX/LINUX) by searching some error text and print some lines above it and some line after it.

So in your command

```
b=1   ## means print only 1 line before the matching line
a=19  ## means print 19 lines after the matching line
s="<Comment>Ericsson_OCS_V1_0.0.0.7" ## means search for this string
/var/opt/fds/config/ServiceConfig/ServiceConfig.cfg ## search in this file
/opt/temp/"$circle"_"$sdpid"_RG.cfg ## store the output in this file
```

Your formatted command is below, the very first condition which was looking like c-->0 before format is easy to interpret which means c-- greater than 0. NR variable in AWK gives the line number of presently processing line in input file being processed.

```
nawk '
 c-- > 0; 
 $0 ~ s
 {
  if(b)
    for(c=b+1;c>1;c--)
      print r[(NR-c+1)%b];
    print;
    c=a
 }
 b 
 {  
   r[NR%b]=$0  
 }' b=1 a=19 s="<Comment>Ericsson_OCS_V1_0.0.0.7" /var/opt/fds/config/ServiceConfig/ServiceConfig.cfg > /opt/temp/"$circle"_"$sdpid"_RG.cfg
```